# Weird behavior with main method

Tags: java, windows, jvm

I have a class like -

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(String s: args){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran this program like > `java Test *` it print the names of all files in that folder. 
 
I don't know whether JVM or windows passes this array instead of ' * ', I would like to know whether this program behaves same on the other platforms(other than windows) and why it behaves in this way? is there any purpose or reason for this?

**NOTE**:
 It doesn't break any of my code but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 15):

I originally thought that this was just the command line shell performing filename expansion. That's what I'd expect under a Unix-like system, but not Windows... but the same occurs for me under Windows, too.

It *doesn't* occur when I write the equivalent C# code... so I suspect it's something in the Java executable launcher doing it. (Note that javaw.exe behaves the same way as java.exe.)

It certainly came as a surprise to me, and I didn't *think* older versions of Java did this on Windows, although [this mailing list post from December 2000](http://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@sources.redhat.com/msg03637.html) suggests I'm wrong. (I'm using an OpenJDK 1.7 JRE.)

I can't find any description of this general case in the [Java Windows documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) - it mentions expansion of classpath entries, but not general arguments.

Comment: yes.. I tried with java 5 and java 6 and it behaves exactly same as I mentioned.

Comment: I think they are emulating the `*` expansion in the java loader on systems like Windows where the usual shell doesn't do it.

Comment: I just searched quite a bit in [the source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/4eed3d0d3293/), and didn't find anything relevant here :-(

Comment: In UNIX it's the job of the shell (as in /bin/bash or whatever you are using) to do this sort of thing. Windows passes everything after the executable name to the executable. There is a method call (`GetSomethingSomething`) which interprets the command line in a standard way. However, that call my be hidden by library magic, with `argv` and `argc` appearing with underscores as `_argv` and `_argc`. Not a fan of Windows.

Comment: (Remember Windows calls `WinMain`, not `main`. On UNIX, you can call a binary directly, and it won't have the arguments mangled. / Doing a search actually finds `GetCommandLine` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx to get the string, and `CommandLineToArgW` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Not until recently (i guess in Java 6) a new feature was added to Java, where '*' is translated to all files in the current directory. This was mainly to avoid need for passing long class paths and giving a platform independent way to pass all jar files in a folder to a classpath.

```
java -cp "lib/*" <mainClass>
```

lib/* would be tranlated to list of file separated by the classpath separator for that platform (i.e. : for unix like and ; for windows) passed to -cp property.

I think this might be the reason for the behavior that you see. I assumed that it was only for specifying classpaths but now I think I was wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

I think command line, first interpret the special operators before passing to java file.

e.g.

```
java Test * > test.txt

java Test Test.????
java Test ^
```

I think its not specific to java.